# Clicking a link on a page that will change the tabs displayed on the new page

Tags: jquery, html, tabs, query-string

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. HTML and CSS is my thing, and Jquery never really works well in my head. But I've been fighting with this and nearly got it working, but struggling on the last bit.

On one page (tabs.html) I have have tabs that change by display blocking/none divs based on the button click

```
<div id="tab-holder">
    <button class="tabs active" onclick="openTab('everyday')"><span>Every Day Menu</span></button>
    <button class="tabs" onclick="openTab('sunday')"><span>Sunday Menu</span></button>
    <button class="tabs" onclick="openTab('buffet')"><span>Buffet Menu</span></button>   
    <button class="tabs" onclick="openTab('xmas')"><span>Christmas Menu</span></button> 
</div>  

<div id="everyday">
   Everyday menu goes here
</div>
<div id="sunday">
   Sunday menu goes here
</div>
<div id="buffet">
   Buffet menu goes here
</div>
<div id="xmas">
   xmas menu goes here
</div>
```

and then for the jquery I use this:

```
function openTab(tabName) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs__content");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"; 
}

var btnContainer = document.getElementById("tab-holder");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("tabs");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
});
}
```

I got this from online, but I'm pretty sure I know how it works.  And it does all work fine!

But I also want to be able to link directly to tabs from other html pages. For example have a link that opens the tabs.html but automatically displays the "buffet" tab.

I was recommended to do it using the query string. So I've got another HTML page that links to tab with

```
<a href="tab-test.html?var1=buffet">Buffet</a>
```

and in tabs.html I've added this code:

```
var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}



$(document).ready(function(){

   var tabName = vars['passTab']
    alert("tabs--"+tabName);

    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs__content");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"; 


})
```

This is good in that it will display the correct tab/div, but I'm struggling to get the buttons to change to the correct active state. From what I gather, the original bit of code changes the active state by listening to the click event and since this is an onload event there's no click. So I'm struggling how to get it to change the button active states.

Sorry this is long but I wanted to explain how I've got to where I've got to.  I'm happy to be pointed in another direction if I'm going about this in the wrong way! :)

Thanks in advance

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually triggering the display state of the tab content, call the `openTab()` function that you already have, passing it the variable:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var tabName = vars['passTab']
   openTab(tabName);
})
```

It will handle the button state and everything else you do when handling tab change via a button click.

You'll also need to change the code that grabs the URL parameters. If you logged `vars['passTab']`, you'd see that it returns `undefined`. Thus, the output of the `alert` should have been different from what you expected.Make `vars` an object instead of an array and remove the line `vars.push(hash[1]);`:

```js
var vars = {}, hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}
```

I made a few changes to your classes and rewrote the `openTab()` function using only jQuery, to provide a readable and working example. It starts up with the xmas tab active, despite the first tab being active in the markup, to fake calling the `openTab()` function with `xmas` from the URL parameter:

```js
function openTab(tabName) {
  // handle active button state
  $('#tab-holder .tab-' + tabName).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
  // handle tab content switching
  $('.tab-content').hide().filter('#' + tabName).show()
}

var vars = {}, hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   var tabName = vars['passTab'];
   // commented out because it won't work in this demo
   // openTab(tabName);
   openTab('xmas')
})
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs.active {
  outline: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-holder">
    <button class="tabs tab-everyday active" onclick="openTab('everyday')"><span>Every Day Menu</span></button>
    <button class="tabs tab-sunday" onclick="openTab('sunday')"><span>Sunday Menu</span></button>
    <button class="tabs tab-buffet" onclick="openTab('buffet')"><span>Buffet Menu</span></button>   
    <button class="tabs tab-xmas" onclick="openTab('xmas')"><span>Christmas Menu</span></button> 
</div>  

<div id="everyday" class="tab-content active">
   Everyday menu goes here
</div>
<div id="sunday" class="tab-content">
   Sunday menu goes here
</div>
<div id="buffet" class="tab-content">
   Buffet menu goes here
</div>
<div id="xmas" class="tab-content">
   xmas menu goes here
</div>
```

On a side note, I wonder why you use jQuery but most of your code uses for loops and native JS functions like `getElementsByClassName`? Adding a library for just using `$(document).ready()` seems like overkill.

Comment: Second this. JQuery has functionality to grab elements by class name really neatly, but if you're only using $.ready(), you might as well just use defer in the script tag on your HTML and not worry about jQuery.

Comment: I tried passing it to the openTab function as suggested, but this still didn't change the active state of the buttons. I'm guessing thats because it doesn't trigger the click event?

As for the use of JQuery, I don't 100% sure what you mean. This isn't my forte so was cobbling it together!

Comment: It doesn't have to trigger the click event, because the click handler only calls the `openTab()` function. So if it works on button click, it has to work when calling the function from the ready callback as well, provided that the strings passed via the query parameter are the same as those provided in the onclick callbacks.

Comment: Does `alert("tabs--"+tabName);` output what you want?

Comment: alert("tabs--"+tabName) did bring back what I wanted, but that was from some earlier testing that I forgot to remove.

Comment: The variable from the URL is getting passed to the openTab function now and it is displaying the correct div based on the variable. But it's still not changing the active state of the buttons. Sorry if I'm being a bit stupid!

Comment: The button switching happened outside of `openTab()` in your code. Please see my onnce again updated answer for a fully working demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

Html

```
<div id="tab-holder">
    <button class="myButton" data-id="everyday"><span>Every Day Menu</span</button>
    <button class="myButton" data-id="sunday"><span>Sunday Menu</span></button>
    <button class="myButton" data-id="buffet"><span>Buffet Menu</span></button>   
    <button class="myButton" data-id="xmas"><span>Christmas Menu</span></button> 
</div>  
<div class="tab-cont">
  <div id="everyday" class="selected">
     Everyday menu goes here
  </div>
  <div id="sunday">
     Sunday menu goes here
  </div>
  <div id="buffet">
     Buffet menu goes here
  </div>
  <div id="xmas">
     xmas menu goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.tab-cont >div{
  display: none;
}
.tab-cont >div.selected{
  display: block;
}
```

Js

```
$(document).on('click','#tab-holder > button', function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('.tab-cont >div').removeClass('selected');
  $('.tab-cont #' + id).addClass('selected');
})
```